# I am trying to write a nodejs that sends and calls functions from the smart contract but to no avail

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So, I am building an Iot device integrated with blockchain on a raspberry pi. I have created a smart contract and deployed it on sepolia testnet. And now for testing, I am writing a nodejs to send a function on the smart contract by passing parameters, and then call a function from the smart contract to display the sent values.

Smart contract -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
// Represents any device connected to the Raspberry Pi that you want to control
struct Appliance {
    uint256 id;
    string name;
    bool status;
    bytes1 pin;
}
 
contract HomeAutomationDemo is Ownable {
    uint256 nextId = 1;
    uint256 count = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Appliance) public appliances;
 
    // Add a new appliance to the list
    function addAppliance(string memory name, bytes1 pin) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[nextId] = Appliance(nextId, name, false, pin);
        nextId++;
        count++;
    }
 
    // Remove an appliance from the list
    function removeAppliance(uint256 id) public onlyOwner {
        delete appliances[id];
        count--;
    }
 
    // This is the function that will be called when the user 
    // toggles the status of the appliance on the mobile app
    function toggleAppliance(uint256 id, bool status) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[id].status = !appliances[id].status;
    }
 
    // Update the details of an appliance
    function updateAppliance(uint256 id, string memory name, bytes1 pin) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[id].name = name;
        appliances[id].pin = pin;
    }
 
    // Get the details of an appliance
    function getAppliance(uint256 id) public view returns (Appliance memory) {
        return appliances[id];
    }
 
    // Get the list of appliances
    function getAppliances() public view returns (Appliance[] memory)  {
        Appliance[] memory result = new Appliance[](count);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < nextId; i++) {
            if (appliances[i].id != 0) {
                result[i] = appliances[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
 
    // Get the total number of appliances
    function getAppliancesCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return count;
    }
 
}
```

Nodejs -

```
const web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require("fs");

const CONTRACT_ABI = `[
        {
                "anonymous": false,
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "previousOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        },
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
                "type": "event"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "addAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "appliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "getAppliance",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance[]",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple[]"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliancesCount",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "owner",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "removeAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "renounceOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "toggleAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "transferOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "updateAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        }
]`;
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x13d9FA79D364070510B410c2FaC1976F21E3e218";

const web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/9e644c118b7c44068674e2d12a776536"));

var myAddress = '0x46Be881Fa6935a8FC969A4ddDFC74d625c558996';
var privateKey = Buffer.from('PRIVATE-KEY', 'hex')
var contractABI =JSON.parse(CONTRACT_ABI);
var contractAddress = CONTRACT_ADDRESS;


contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);



// first populate an appliance
let setAppliance = contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", 1).send;

console.log(setAppliance);

let applianceOnOff = contract.methods.getAppliances;
console.log(applianceOnOff);
```

And this is what I get when running the nodejs -

```
[Function: bound _executeMethod] {
  request: [Function: bound _executeMethod]
}
[Function: bound _createTxObject]
```

Comment: When sharing code snippets online, always remember to remove any secret credentials in your code. I can see something like a private key in your code snippets. If that is a real wallet private key, DO NOT USE IT TO STORE FUNDS ANYMORE, it's compromised.

Comment: @AhmedMohammed Thanks for pointing out. Its an ethereum test wallet, so I thought it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```js
contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", 1).send;
```

returns a Promise in which you have to wait for its completion by using the `await` keyword:

```js
await contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", web3.utils.numberToHex(1)).send({from: myAddress});

/* 
* web3.utils.numberToHex(1) converts decimal digit '1' to bytes '0x1'
* because the addAppliance function takes a 'byte1' as second parameter 
*/
```

For this line: `contract.methods.getAppliances;`, you are making a call to get a value from your contract which doesn't modify state so you have to append `.call()` to get that value, `.send()` is used when making calls tha triggers smart contract state changes.

You can then use the `await` keyword to wait for its completion or use a callback:

```js
await contract.methods.getAppliances().call();
```

Comment: I used a callback like you suggested and I get the following error: 
/home/pi/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/lib/index.js:245
            if (param.substring(0, 2) === '0x') {
                      ^

TypeError: param.substring is not a function

Comment: Can you use `await` instead?

Comment: Tried it and but it didn't return anything.

async function setAppliance(error, result) {
let setAppliance = await contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", 1).send().then(function(error, result){});
console.log(setAppliance);
}
async function applianceOnOff(error, result)  {
let applianceOnOff = await contract.methods.getAppliances().call().then(function(error,result){});
console.log(applianceOnOff);
}

Comment: I just made an edit to the answer, adding the `await` keyword that way instead of a callback should suffice.

Comment: Changed the code like you suggested and it still doesn't return anything. async function setAppliance(error, result) {
let setAppliance = await contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", 1).send();
console.log(setAppliance);
}
async function applianceOnOff(error, result)  {
let applianceOnOff = await contract.methods.getAppliances().call();
console.log(applianceOnOff);
}

Comment: I think the calling function is working now with this code. `async function main () {

let applianceOnOff = await contract.methods.getAppliances().call();
console.log(applianceOnOff);
}

main()
 .then(() => process.exit(0))
 .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
});
`

I got an array returned [],..

However, for sending parameters, its showing the param.substring error.. Can you suggest me a fix for this?

Comment: I found that you need to add a `from` to the `send()`, I'll now edit the answer again.

Comment: I added the edits. The `from` address is the address that is signing the transaction, also your contract take a byte parameter instead of a normal number for the `pin`, hence, the line `web3.utils.numberToHex(1)`

Comment: Worked, but to an another error :( `Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not avalable` I am assuming this is probably a problem caused by infura?

Comment: The signer is not actually initialised properly.
Add this line to get a signer from your private key then pass it to the `from` parameter in the `send` function:
`const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey [, ignoreLength ]);`

Comment: ANother TypeError `TypeError: Cannot read property 'accounts' of undefined
    at main (/home/pi/sepolia/test2.js:272:32)`
Code - `const account = await web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('//private-key//');

let setAppliance = await contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", web3.utils.numberToHex(1)).send({from: account});
`